# TTask[n] EThreadNameException

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Experts, take the following code snippet below:

```
var
  aAllTasks : Array [0..1] of ITask  //global private var

Procedure SetImage();
begin

  //..      
  //.. Get a URL of an image stored on a server     
  //..

  aAllTasks[0] := TTask.Run(
    Procedure
    begin
      // Download the Image and display the image
    end);

  aAllTasks[1] := TTask.Run(
    Procedure
    begin
      // Get the rating of the image from a REST server
    end);

end;
```

when the debugger hits

```
      aAllTasks[1] := TTask.Run(...);
```

I get

**First chance exception at $001A30B5. Exception class EThreadNameException with message ''. Process APPNAME (126391)**

It throws the exception but it does not seem to crash the App

This only happens when debugging/running iOS apps 

iOS 9.2

RS 10 Seattle (with Update 1)

PA server 17.0 (with hotfix.. V 8.0.1.52)

Xcode version 7.2 (7C68)

What would cause this and how would I fix it?

Comment: Whomever down votes please state why, I may be able to amend the question and add more info or make it more clear.

Comment: Please do not put information in the title that you're able to include in the tags. It's unnecessary (the tag system works extremely well), it's a waste of space you could use for more information about the problem, and it's inefficient when users find the question in a search result (they have to wade through the unnecessary noise to get to the actual content). Thanks.

Comment: You may be getting downvotes because you've failed to provide code that actually demonstrates the problem;. what you posted is just meaningless. You should read the [How to create a minimial, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference.

Comment: Thanks @Ken White, I'll follow the "How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example" guidelines in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code calls, `TThread.NameThreadForDebugging`. That looks like this:

```
class procedure TThread.NameThreadForDebugging(AThreadName: string; AThreadID: TThreadID);
{$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
.... // windows specific code removed
{$ELSE MSWINDOWS}
const
  cExceptionMessage = 'Type=$1000,Name=%s,ThreadID=%d,Flags=0';
  EMBDBKPRESENTNAME = 'EMB_DBK_PRESENT';
{$IF Defined(MACOS)}
  OLDEMBDBKPRESENTNAME = 'EMB_MACOSX_DBK_PRESENT';                                                                             
{$ENDIF}
begin
{$IF Defined(MACOS)}
  if (getenv(EMBDBKPRESENTNAME) <> nil) or (getenv(OLDEMBDBKPRESENTNAME) <> nil) then
{$ELSEIF Defined(ANDROID)}
  if (System.DebugHook <> 0) or (getenv(EMBDBKPRESENTNAME) <> nil) then
{$ELSE}
  if (getenv(EMBDBKPRESENTNAME) <> nil) then
{$ENDIF}
  begin
    try
      raise EThreadNameException.Create(
        Format(cExceptionMessage, [AThreadName, AThreadID]));
    except
    end;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF !MSWINDOWS}
```

This function is called when you wish to give your thread a name. Now, thread objects do not have names. So when you give your thread a name, it is for debugging purposes only. The debugger keeps track of the names you provide, and associates them with thread IDs. Then when the debugger presents information about threads, it can look up the name from the ID and present that to you. But this is purely a debugger mechanism because the operating system does not support thread names.

So, how do you signal to the debugger that you wish to give a thread a name. Well, you throw a specific exception. The debugger is aware of the exception and gets the first chance to handle the exception. The debugger receives the name and the thread ID in the exception text and makes a note of that information.

Notice that the exception is swallowed immediately and so this does not interrupt the flow of the program.

So, it is normal for this exception to be raised, to be handled by the debugger, and not to impact on the behaviour of the program. What is odd is that the debugger is breaking on that exception. I would have expected that exception to be ignored by the debugger, by default.

An old QC report ([QC#105310](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105310)) for OSX describes exactly the behaviour that you are observing. That issue was closed and marked as fixed in XE7. Perhaps this issue has re-surfaced, or perhaps it was never fixed for the mobile platforms. I suggest that you submit a bug report to Quality Portal.